# How secure is identifying users in email links

Tags: email

I've always assumed that it's risky to identify users in urls within emails. For example, let's say my app is something like eventBrite. I'm inviting a set of users to an upcoming event. I create unique urls for each user's email which allows them to simply click those url's in the email to accept or decline. Ie, they will not have to authenticate with the website.

If they view the email on a mobile device or a public computer through webmail, then clicking the links will fully accept/decline.

Is this approach too risky? I had assumed you should avoid this as something could see those urls and make requests on them which would trigger false accepts/declines.

Comment: How would your URL look like ? Can you give a specific example ?

Comment: I can't imagine it's more insecure than any other message that you might send through email.  Plus, most hackers are not spending their time maliciously accepting EventBrite invitations.

Comment: It's fine if it's for a single time-limited request, but you should not do what Facebook did and automatically log people in. That's a gaping security hole.

Comment: I haven't created the url. It can look however I like. Basically I'll generate some sort of random token we place in the url and store in our DB. Then we'll listen and look it up.

Answer (score 3):

It'a an opinion but I would assume the link itself can be more secure than the email actually. You can make the accept link valid only through certain period of time (it would not make much sense otherwise anyways).

Moreover, you can make it pretty much arbitrary long. So it's basically arbitrarily hard to guess.

That would leave two options to "see" the link, that I can think of. Physically seeing it by eaves dropping. But you could generate a mail in the html form, which would allow you to hide the full link behind a hyper-ref text. Like [Accept](https://my.email.api/accept/v3ry_scrt_l0ng_unique_rndm_c0d3) / [Decline](https://my.email.api/decline/v3ry_scrt_l0ng_unique_rndm_c0d3).

Answer (score 1):

There are several parts to this answer:

**Is it secure?** Absolutely not.  It's security through obscurity.  You're betting somebody can't guess the link which, as long as it's a finite string then they totally can and as soon as they do, they can RSVP to your event.

**Follow up** Does it matter? Probably not. I imagine the chances of somebody trying to spoof an RSVP to an event are pretty slim.  I absolutely wouldn't protect anything critical this way but if you're just doing something like event RSVP etc (no money changing hands) I don't see anything wrong with this approach.  As luk32 said, you can also make the links valid for limited amounts of time etc.

The real issue here, (unless there's something you're not telling us and this is somehow a high value target) is how likely is somebody to accidentally stumble on one of these links and RSVP to an event they aren't going to?  You can make the chances of that exceedingly unlikely by generating the links in a sufficiently random manner so that no two links are a like.  In this case, I don't think *security* is the big concern so much as data integrity.  That is, is the data you're receiving valid.

Comment: Well, every password/passphrase is a finite string that can be guessed. Probably easier than a random one. Heck, most modern cryptographic systems that are created right against the "security by obscurity" rule you are bringing up, are based on the fact that you can guess the number to decipher it, and they bet you won't (at least in time that it is relevant).

Comment: @luk32 You're right, any finite string can be guessed.  Really the key is whether it's random or not.  If it's random, chances are slim.  However if it's something like the event name and then a number, probably pretty easy to guess...

Comment: agreed all around. I will have them timeout. As well, in the case a url is followed and the user is NOT authenticated then I will make this clear in the email we send the user with a note and the opportunity for them to indicate it was NOT them who took this action.

Comment: @ChrisThompson I totally agree with you on the part where it is dangerous to protect anything with something that can be guessed. Nowadays standard encryption methods actually requite data to be re-ciphered with stronger keys periodically. However, in OP's case data naturally invalidates after period of time. Also it is not said that the confirmation link is some kind of plain-text like data. That would be stupid. I imagine it as one-time random code it does not to have contain any data within.